# The string variable passed through an xpath is not locating the element and throwing an exception

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
public static void selectNavigationLink(String mainMenu, String subMenu) {

    WebElement mm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='+mainMenu+']")));
    mm.click();

    WebElement sm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'+subMenu+')]")));
    sm.click();
}
```

I was told to write the script where I have to pass the variable into the xpath to make it more robust but the attribute value that is passed as variable to the xpath is not locating an element but when I pass it directly as an attribute value inside the xpath, it locates an element.  And, this is the error message I am getting--

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[normalize-space()='+mainMenu+']"

Comment: You mean you're trying to select a DOM element with Java? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JeremyThille yes. do you have any idea why i am not able to locate an element? but when i replace mainmenu with Contact and submenu with New contacts inside the xpath. it locates an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the variable inside xpath is wrong. Please try following :

```
public static void selectNavigationLink(String mainMenu, String subMenu) {

WebElement mm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='" + mainMenu + "']")));
mm.click();

WebElement sm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + subMenu + "')]")));
sm.click();
```

}

Comment: Yea, my lead helped me with that in the morning. thank you so much :)